# Why does the for loop only prints the same kind of filename type and not other filename types in python?

Tags: python, file, for-loop

This is the data in `CFS_Config.txt`. The Folder Path will be stored in the `root_dir`. The `source_documents` folder contain the 2 different files.

```
Folder Path = C:\Users\user\Documents\Lynn\FYPJ P3\FYP updated 9.10.18 (Tues) trying\FYP\dataprep\source_documents
ED Notes name = Notes
Admission name = Adm
Discharge name = Dis
Output = ../dataprep/docs2txt_output
```

This is the codes where all files will be loop in the for loop and then print in text file (in `docx2txt.py`)

```
    def read_config():

    # open existing file to read configuration
    cfs_config_txt = open("../CFS_Config.txt", "r")

    file_list = []
    root_dir = ""
    ednotes_name = ""
    admission_name = ""
    discharge_name = ""
    output = ""

    for line in cfs_config_txt:
        file_list.append(line)

    if "Folder Path = " in file_list[0]:
        root_dir = str(file_list[0])
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("Folder Path = ", "")
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("\n", "")

    if "ED Notes name = " in file_list[1]:
        ednotes_name = str(file_list[1])
        ednotes_name = ednotes_name.replace("ED Notes name = ", "")
        ednotes_name = ednotes_name.replace("\n", "")

    if "Admission name = " in file_list[2]:
        admission_name = str(file_list[2])
        admission_name = admission_name.replace("Admission name = ", "")
        admission_name = admission_name + ".txt"
        admission_name = admission_name.replace("\n", "")

    if "Discharge name = " in file_list[3]:
        discharge_name = str(file_list[3])
        discharge_name = discharge_name.replace("Admission name = ", "")
        discharge_name = discharge_name + ".txt"
        discharge_name = discharge_name.replace("\n", "")

    if "Output = " in file_list[4]:
        output = str(file_list[4])
        output = output.replace("Output = ", "")
        output = output + ".txt"
        output = output.replace("\n", "")

    return root_dir, ednotes_name, admission_name, discharge_name, output

 #Below is the codes to loop every file in the root_dir. The root_dir will 
  contain the folder path that read from the CFS_Config.txt file.

def convert_txt(choices):

root_dir, ednotes_name, admission_name, discharge_name, output = 
read_config()


if(choices == 1):

    # open new file to write string data textfile
    text_file = open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    text_file.write("cat_id|content\n")

    for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
        source_directory = root_dir + '/' + filename
        getFilenameOnly = os.path.basename(source_directory)
        #print(getFilenameOnly)
        whole_string = ""
        document = ""

        document += docx2txt.process(source_directory)
        print(document)


        if ednotes_name in getFilenameOnly:
            arr = ednotes_extractor.get_ednotes(source_directory)
            list2str = str(arr)
            c = cleanString(newstring=list2str)
            new_arr = []
            new_arr += [c]
            # open existing file to append the items in the array to the previously written textfile
            text_file = open(output, 'a', encoding='utf-8')
            for item in new_arr:
                text_file.write("%s\n" % item)

        elif admission_name in getFilenameOnly:
            categoryType = ('_'.join(getFilenameOnly.split('_')[1:3]))
            categoryType = categoryType.replace("_", "")
            categoryType = categoryType.replace("Cat", "")
            categoryType = categoryType.replace(" ", "")

            for word in document.split():
                whole_string += word + " "

            whole_string = delete_phrase(whole_string)
            whole_string = delete_header(whole_string)

            text_file = open(output, "a", encoding='utf-8')
            text_file.write("\n")
            text_file.write(categoryType + '|' + whole_string)
```

When I print `root_dir`, there are two different files in it.

```
The output of print(root_dir):

883056_Cat_7_Notes.docx

883434_Cat_7_Patient_Adm.docx

883056_Cat_7_Patient_Dis.docx

683700_Cat_6_Notes.docx

588300_Cat_6_Patient_Dis.docx

588817_Cat_4_Notes.docx
```

The problem is that they only print the data for all 
`.......Notes.docx` files.
Please help me take a look at the codes, thanks!! :((

Comment: Where do you call `read_config()`? Where do you use those results?

Comment: I have edited my codes please check^ @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you define the variable `ednotes_name` in your config to be `Notes` therefore only the files having `Notes` after three `_` are read by your script.